# How do I require multiple input fields in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to write a simple page with a couple of inputs which should be `required` to not be empty.

Here's the code to do that (self-contained):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
            app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            }]);
        </script>
        <style>
            input.ng-invalid {
                background-color: pink;
            }
            input.ng-valid {
                background-color: lightgreen;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            Description: *<input type="text" id="input-description" ng-model="req-text" required></input><br/>
            Order: *<input type="number" id="input-order" ng-model="req-number" value="100" step="100" required></input><br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I was hoping it would do is start with the text field being blank and red (invalid), and the number field being `100` and green (valid).

The first thing I tried was setting both `ng-model`s for the inputs to the same thing, but that caused the number field to update the text field when it was updated (but not the other way around).

Since that obviously didn't work, I tried using different models for the inputs, as shown in my code. However, now both inputs have a value of `0` (even the text field, which should still be blank), and both inputs cannot be typed into or otherwise edited.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I just get both inputs to be `required` separately by Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong first of all is using illegal identifiers for models. `req-number` is not a valid identifier for a variable. (remember all of these models are actually refered as `$scope.variableName`, imagine `$scope.req-number`). Hence your inputs are made readonly. You can actually see that when you examine console of your browser.

Second, html attribute `value` is ignored for `input` in this case. Use controller function to set default values for your models.

```
   app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.req_number = 100;
   }]);
   ....
   <div ng-controller="myController">
        Description: *<input type="text" ng-model="req_text" REQUIRED><br/>
        Order: *<input type="number" ng-model="req_number" required><br/>
   </div>
```

Alternatively you can use `ng-init` to initiate the model. However as mentioned by @developer0333, this is not recommended because initialization logic is part of business logic and with project evolving can get more complicated then just setting primitive values.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="req_number" ng-init="req_number=100" required><br/>
```

[Plunker with correct code](http://plnkr.co/edit/3MRNlbsmwmPm4VRMn9uy?p=preview)

**PS** and a small remark, closing tags are ignored for `<input>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems I was rather confused on what `ng-model` did. I didn't realize that (1) it was going to be a variable in the scope, and (2) that this variable would be the value of the input. I thought that models were something else entirely.

Comment: `ngInit` directive shouldn't be used in this case, as it's on docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit. Start the value in **controller** in this case.

Comment: @developer033, that's what I usually do. But as the question contained very simple code and controller was empty I proposed `ng-init`. I will reflect your remark in my answer